# When using logging in Python, the locale is set, and the log cannot be obtained

Tags: python-3.x, locale, chinese-locale

I'm trying to use logging module in Python. It works well expect when I set the loacle.

Here is the sample code(*python3.9*):

```
import logging
import locale
from time import asctime

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    filename="test.log",
    encoding="utf-8",
    filemode="w",
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
)

logging.info("before")
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "zh_CN.UTF-8")
logging.info("after")
```

The program exit with: `Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)`

When I check `test.log`. I only got this:

`2023-07-14 10:37:43 - root - INFO - before`

It missed that log record of `after`.

In my limited experience with pyhton.
I have done some research in Google and other Q&A community.
The problem seems to be related to the `asctime`.
But I still can't know the deeper reason.

I want to know why when I set the locale, the logging can't works anymore. And I want to know how to get log after when I set the locale in Python like that.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the code you showed, the program terminates and I get a stack backtrace that shows the error.  In my case, the error is:

`locale.Error: unsupported locale setting`

This is an exception that was raised because my system does not support the requested locale.

If you are not getting a stack backtrace, but it's silently quitting, that's more mysterious.  It is possible to disable the stack backtrace.

Another thing you could try is to wrap the `setlocale()` call in a `try:` block and see what you get.  Example:

```
try:
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "zh_CN.UTF-8")
except Exception as e:
    print(repr(e))
```

In my case it prints the same exception I listed above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do not get this Error `locale.Error: unsupported locale setting` . May be caused by the region reason.  And,  I'm sorry I forgot to give my console output.  When I run my code.  I got: `Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)`.